# How do I vertically align multiple children elements of a parent element

Tags: html, css

For my example, I'm copying the styles and structure from the new [Marvel App](https://marvelapp.com) site. I'm wanting to accomplish the way they have an element 'house' their logo and their navigation. As you can see from their source, as well as mine, there seems to be a lot of elements at play with this method. There are two things I want to know:

1.) What's causing my copied code not being able to mimic the way Marvel has it? What am I doing wrong?

2.) Can this be simplified with less, more manageable code?

My code that I copied, for practice purposes, is below along with a link to the codepen.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header-bar-wrapper headroom headroom--top" id="header">

  <div class="height-100 pageWrap">
    <nav class="navHeight">
      <a href="#" class="float-left height-100">
        <div class="display-table height-100">
          <div class="display-tableCell verticalAlign-middle">
            <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" class="display-block" width="40px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#00E06A;}
</style>
<rect class="st0" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>

          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="navigation-links"> 
        <div class="display-table height-100">
          <div class="display-tableCell verticalAlign-middle">
            <div class="breakPointM-inline breakPoint-textAlign-right">
              <div class="navigation-link-wrapper wrapper-one breakPointM-marginRight-m breakPointL-paddingRight-s">
                <a href="#" class="link navigation-link link link--light">Features</a>
              </div>
               <div class="navigation-link-wrapper wrapper-one breakPointM-marginRight-m breakPointL-paddingRight-s">
                <a href="#" class="link navigation-link link link--light">Pricing</a>
              </div
                  <div class="navigation-link-wrapper wrapper-one breakPointM-marginRight-m breakPointL-paddingRight-s">
                <a href="#" class="link navigation-link link link--light">Blog</a>
              </div
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header-bar-wrapper {
  min-height: 70px;
  z-index: 200;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
}

.pageWrap:after, .breakPointM-inline:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

.pageWrap:before, .breakPointM-inline:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.pageWrap {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.navHeight {
  height: 100%;
}

.float-left {
  float: left;
}

.height-100 {
  height: 100%;
}

.width-90, .pageWrap {
  width: 90%;
}

.display-block {
  display: block;
}

.display-table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.display-tableCell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.verticalAlign-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigation-links {
  z-index: 300;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.breakPointM-inline {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.navigation-link-wrapper {
  transform: translateY(0);
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.breakPointM-marginRight-m {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMBozE?editors=1100)

Comment: As I understood, You copied the page source?

Comment: @CapeStar Yes, as best as I could.

Comment: Do you think, you have all the classes and files to mimic their layouts?

Comment: @CapeStar I believe so. I inspected each element, grabbed the tags, and grabbed the styles. I can't imagine there's more to achieve what I need.

Comment: I think I am missing something because for example I cant find "display-table height-100" class.

Comment: @CapeStar Both .display-table and .height-100 are in my CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've played around a little with this, supported only HTML5 and CSS3.
Dont bother pasting into codepen or jsfiddle, test it locally on actual browser.

I've colored the green area for your logo image
You'll notice what I've done in the CSS is simply centered the anchor tags inside the list item elements using the CSS transform:translate. 
and floated the list items to the right of the nav element.. let me know what you think.

### HTML

```
<head>
<title> Alternative </title>
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>

<header>

<div id="logo"></div>
<nav>
<ul>
<li> <a href="#">Home</a>    </li>
<li> <a href="#">About</a>   </li>
<li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
</ul>

</nav>
</header>

</body>
```

### CSS

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html, body {

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

header {

    height:15%;
    position:relative;
}
#logo {

    background-color:green;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}

nav {
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;

}

li {
    width:20%;
    float:right;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    list-style-type:none;

}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying and pasting code directly from another website most of the time is a horrible idea, mainly for a few reasons:

1 . You don't acquire the necessary skills to tackle problems which are not  solvable by copy and paste.

2.You don't gain insight on how exactly the code works, neither you can see properly which framework they are using in order to construct the given website.

3 . Regarding your question 1, if you have to copy the entire source code and you are wondering what is not right...everything you've done is wrong.

4 . In my opinion it can be done it more easily manageable code because "table" is horribly outdated.

I hope my answer helped in some way.